# How to send Escape Key event using PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, phantomjs

I need to send Escape Key event on a site using PhantomJS.

Unable to find any solution. In addition I also need a way to refresh/reload same page.

Correct answer to any one of the above question will solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to send escape.

`var page = webPage.create();
page.sendEvent('keypress', page.event.key.Escape)`

Comment: can you share the website link, if its public?

Comment: @HimanshuTiwari Punit Gupta probably meant `page.event.key.Escape` instead of `page.event.Escape`